# Kong + Lambda Plugin - how to enable retries?

Tags: lambda, kong

I have a Kong service that uses the AWS Lambda plugin to call a function (sync - `RequestResponse`).
It occurs that, from what I understood, there’s no way to enable retries as Lambda always returns `OK`.
Even with a transformation plugin to generate the actual status (reading from the `status` property in the response json), I can’t make retries work.

Are there any plugins to enable retries for Lambda calls? Or how should I proceed to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware Kong Lambda plugin does not support retries although there is a workaround for this use case.

An internal route can be created, that executes Lambda call (Lambda Plugin with route id and service id specified) and another route that would be targeted from outside, this route would have the retry enable and calls the internal route. here is the example of how I achieved this:

Service:

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "created_at": 1555418486,
  "connect_timeout": 30000,
  "id": "3c31fc3f-74f1-423f-8e5a-751668bed878",
  "protocol": "http",
  "name": "test",
  "read_timeout": 10000,
  "port": 8000,
  "path": "/kong-internal/",
  "updated_at": 1555418486,
  "retries": 3,
  "write_timeout": 10000,
  "tags": null,
  "extras": {}
}
```

Public facing route:

```
{
  "updated_at": 1555418553,
  "created_at": 1555418487,
  "strip_path": true,
  "snis": null,
  "hosts": [
    "test.com"
  ],
  "name": "EXTERNAL_route",
  "methods": [],
  "sources": null,
  "preserve_host": true,
  "regex_priority": 1,
  "service": {
    "id": "3c31fc3f-74f1-423f-8e5a-751668bed878"
  },
  "paths": [],
  "destinations": null,
  "id": "0917748d-24eb-42aa-b83e-7111ef4de9b4",
  "protocols": [
    "https",
    "http"
  ],
  "tags": null
}
```

Internal route (has lambda plugin):

```
{
  "updated_at": 1555418487,
  "created_at": 1555418487,
  "strip_path": true,
  "snis": null,
  "hosts": [
    "test.com"
  ],
  "name": "INTERNAL_route",
  "methods": null,
  "sources": null,
  "preserve_host": false,
  "regex_priority": null,
  "service": {
    "id": "3c31fc3f-74f1-423f-8e5a-751668bed878"
  },
  "paths": [
    "/kong-internal/"
  ],
  "destinations": null,
  "id": "e5981f16-d44c-4d19-b706-cdc3173db412",
  "protocols": [
    "http"
  ],
  "tags": null
}
```

Although there is still a catch, `strip_path` does not apply to lambda function, so the lambda should remove `/kong-internal/` from path manually.

Note: if your lambda adds `x-amz-log-result` header I suggest to add `response_transform` plugin to internal route to remove it, it can get pretty big and fail the call.

EDIT: turns out Kong doesn't really like the timeout status from aws, so it make sense to have high connect_timeout on service and relatively lower read_timeout and write_timeout, then the internal mechanism of kong will do the retrying.

Comment: Interesting approach, will give it a try.

Comment: @dmmd  in original answer connect_timeout was wrongly set to 10s, when you are trying the approach please try it to 30s.